# Matplotlib color normalizations

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to have two color normalizations for the same image in matplotlib?

For example, how can I use colors.BoundaryNorm to get discrete color palette and colors.TwoSlopeNorm or MidpointNormalization to get a midpoint in the palette?

Regards.